# set Ringtone using mp3 from res/raw folder

Tags: android, logging, ringtone

well, I tried some ways and not works none yet. The way more "correct" is this (I think), I really need help, Im coming crazy! :)

```
public void setRingtone(){
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = nombreActual+".mp3";

        File newSoundFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);
        Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.genaut.ringtonelists/raw/"+sonidoActual);//sonidoActual (sound name  without .mp3)
        ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
        AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
        try {
            soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            soundFile=null;   
        }

        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
            int i = fis.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
            }

            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, nombreActual);
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

           Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
           Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

           RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Main.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

    Log.d("AbsolutePath: ", newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d("DefaultUri: ", RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Main.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE).toString());
    }
```

I have this permissions on manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried some codes, tried mixing some steps (copying the file, and setting the library ..)  but no works. Im really stucks with this. With this code, I can add my sound to (Settings - Device - Audio profiles - "Select a profile" - Voice call ringtone) but it isn't selected by default, and if I select him, he don't play any sound :(

I dont see the sound file on any location on SD, and the Log are:

```
08-05 03:20:22.362: D/AbsolutePath:(6277): /mnt/sdcard/Ding Ding Dong.mp3
08-05 03:20:22.364: D/DefaultUri:(6277): content://media/external/audio/media/15233
```

**This example: the "Ding Ding Dong.mp3" file and others that I copied, are on sdcard but with a size of 0!!**.

Comment: So have you got it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try To do This Code,,All the best

```
File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

Comment: The only difference betweent the codes are the Duration metadata, I think that these arent the problem, my problem are the step when I copy the mp3 to sd. I really thanks your help :) but not works yet

Comment: @jenuine Can you please tell me how do you specify the path?